# How to query an array of objects in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using ActiveRecord, where I am trying to query a model of Courses. Every Course has the following schema:

```
Courses: 
[{
    name: "Intro to Math",
    id: 1,
    segments: [{id: 1, subject_id: "123-456"}, {id: 1, subject_id: "789-145"}]
},
{
    name: "Intro to Probability",
    id: 2,
    segments: [{id: 1, subject_id: "123-456"}, {id: 1, subject_id: "000-000"}]
},
{
    name: "Intro to Stats",
    id: 3,
    segments: [{id: 1, subject_id: "111-111"}, {id: 1, subject_id: "000-000"}]
}]
```

How would I write an ActiveRecord query that would get me every Course which has a segment which has the id "123-456" (which in this case, would be the Course with the id 1 & 2)?

Comment: is `segments` a json type column?

Answer (score 1):

```
Course.joins(:segments).where(segments: { subject_id: "123-456" })
```

For more information and examples, please refer to [the documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins).

Answer (score -1):

From this statement: `Course which has a segment which has the id "123-456" (which in this case, would be the Course with the id 1 & 2)`, seems you meant `Course which has a segment which has the segment_id "123-456"`
If that is the case:

```
Courses.joins(:segments).where("segments.subject_id='123-456'")
```